# PHP GET, if / esle

Tags: php, if-statement, get

What's wrong with this code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['variable'] == "a") {
    $variable = "a";
}
else {
    $variable = "b" 
}
echo $variable;
?>
```

I get an internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$variable = 'b';
if (isset($_GET['hop']) && $_GET['hop'] == "a")
{
    $variable = 'a';
}

echo $variable;
?>
```

For an explanation on what you did wrong look here: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: This does something different (`$variable` cannot get `"b" anymore) and `NOTICE`s are not `ERROR`s (`NOTICE`s doesn't break execution). It's cleaner with `isset()` (or something like that), but it cannot cause the problem.

Comment: +1: Because this is a much better way to initialize variables.

Comment: Indeed, but don't confuse matters by transforming the code structure!

Comment: @KingCrunch: You don't want any notices in your code. If you minimize them, those that do surface means you have a possible error in the code. Yes, `$variable` can get b: if the variable isn't equal to "a"!

Comment: Except for the extra opening bracket in `$_GET['[hop']` derp

Comment: *don't confuse matters by transforming the code structure*, This is far from confusing, and im not just providing an answer, im also showing how to code efficiently

Comment: Thanks @imoda, small oversight

Comment: @phant0m: (Hi again ^^) For some reason I missed the first line. OK, `$variable` can get `"b"` ;) About the other thing: I'm on your side, that notices are (a kind of) bad too. See my "It's cleaner..." in my comment above.

Comment: @RobertPitt Typoes will be the end of us.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Ah, it just sounded as if you found them to be negligible and not something to pay attention to ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to improve the code. Besides the missing ; my original code didn't work properly. Yours does.

Comment: @Robert: Why do you suggest that this will be more efficient?

Comment: @oli, The code above may not be more efficient, but over a large application small changes in the right area will have an effect on the efficiency of the application, it's about clean and more practical code as well.

Answer (score 4):

You missed a semicolon here: `$variable = "b";`

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is missing in else part $variable.

```
else {
    $variable = "b"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the trailing `;` on the `$variable = "b"` line.

Answer (score 0):

Propably the missing `;`  in line 6

```
    $variable = "b";
```

Because some other answer provide alternatives too

```
echo isset($_GET['hop']) && ($_GET['hop'] == "a")
     ? 'a'
     : 'b';
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Mising a semicolon

```
$variable = "b";
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semi-colon does not give an internal server error. Check to see if you have a .htaccess file in the root and if its configured correctly.

Comment: Yes it does, On servers such as Nginx you get an internal server error because the fast-cgi return's an error code, this in Nginx will throw an internal server error by default, you have to configure it properly in order to pass the errors to the output buffer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227093/php-fpm-returns-http-500-for-all-php-errors