# how can i prevent a user generated query string from processing

Tags: php, mysql, query-string, sql-injection

i am using a PHP, MySQL based application in which some requests to the server-side code from front end are done using GET requests.
In the server-side, I get those values using `$_GET[variable]`..

typical URL i use for it as:

```
http://localhost/mysite/processdata.php?variable='somedata'
```

say the above URL is generated and sent to server when a user performs an action. but the user can always change the querystring in the URL.. 
is there a mechanism to find whether the querystring is generated by the application or by a user? and prevent the processing if its generated by a user/ non-authorised program?

Comment: (*In a nutshell*) - Set up `if/else` conditions that if the `GET` doesn't match the set conditions, stop execution. [See an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6447617/1415724)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks for ur response Fred.. its nt only abt different variables.. but different values for the same variable.. such as: variable='data1' is valid if generated by the app.. but its nt valid if user generates that query string.. because he can then use variable='data2' as well..

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if `variable='data2'` doesn't exist in the query/code, then that example above (replaced with your choice of commands) is for just that; `if` condition meets variable, then `do something`.

Answer (score 0):

You can never tell if your app sent it or the user sent it. However you *can* validate your information. For example:

```
$value = $_GET['variable'];
// Assuming you want the variable to be an integer
if ( preg_match( '/^\D+$/', $value ) ) {
  // Use value for what you need
}
else {
  // Show error
}
```

However you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. There are a number of libraries out there that come with that feature standard. [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules) is one example. [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html) is another. I prefer CI, but you should take a look and decide for yourself. Either way it comes down to validation all the time.